# Using statement with unknown implementation?

Tags: c#

Can the following code be translated into using the... ejem... 'using' statement?

```
TextReader TheReader;
if( UploadedFile ) { TheReader = new System.IO.StreamReader( LocalFileName ); }
else { TheReader = new System.IO.StringReader( Input ); }
//Use The reader
TheReader.Close();
```

So `using (TextReader TheReader = ??)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could use the conditional operator:

```
// Variable names changed for convention, and fully-qualified names simplified
using (TextReader reader = uploadedFile ? File.OpenText(localFileName)
                                        : (TextReader) new StringReader(input))
{
    ...
}
```

The cast to `TextReader` can be on either of the last two operands - it's just to let the compiler know the type of the expression, as it can't just find the common type (`TextReader`) from `StreamReader` (the 2nd operand) and `StringReader` (the third).

You *could* assign the variable before the `using` statement as per Guffa's answer - but personally I'd use this code, to keep the scope of the variable limited to the `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Although you already have two good answers, there is at least a third that also deserves a mention, and may in some cases be more appropriate: use one more function.

```
TextReader CreateReader()
{
    if( UploadedFile )
        return new System.IO.StreamReader( LocalFileName );
    else
        return new System.IO.StringReader( Input );
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
using (TextReader reader = CreateReader())
{
}
```

Comment: I like this one! It gives you more flexibility when selecting the concrete implementation, in case there's more than two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not that way. If you can't create the instance in the `using` statement. Be careful about the scope of the variable, though, as the scope of the variable is outside the `using` block. You can use a block around the code to limit the scope of the variable:

```
{
  TextReader TheReader;
  if( UploadedFile ) { TheReader = new System.IO.StreamReader( LocalFileName ); }
  else { TheReader = new System.IO.StringReader( Input ); }
  using (TheReader) {
    //Use The reader
  }
}
```

Comment: I though on using that, but it's discouraged: "You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case, the object remains in scope..." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @ElServas: Yes, I already added a warning about that. You can use a code block to limit the scope of the variable.